# How to redirect hash route to base on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Lets say I have the following routes:

```
/
/user
/fruits
/fruits/#/apple
/fruits/#/pear
```

When I am on /fruits/#/apple, and refresh the page, I would like to redirect back to /fruits.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/fruits">
          <HashRouter>
            <>
              <h1> Fruit shop </h1>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/apple" component={Apple} />
                <Route path="/pear" component={Pear} />
                <Redirect to="/apple" />
              </Switch>
            </>
            </HashRouter>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/user" component={Users} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect a refresh on a page using `window.performance.navigation.type` where the value is 1 if the page was refreshed. In your Apple or Pear component, you can check this value in the componentDidMount function or in a useEffect hook and redirect to /fruits in any way you prefer if needed.

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(window.performance.navigation.type === 1){
        //Do your redirect here
    }
}
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(window.performance.navigation.type === 1){
        //Do your redirect here
    }
}, [])
```

Depending on if you are using functional components or not